# Add Crosswalk to Android App Project and generate apks with arm or x86 architectures

Tags: android, webview, x86, arm

I have an Android project that uses WebView. I want to add Crosswalk to use it instead WebView. I have followed the instructions to embed it and I've seen that there is two, one for ARM and other for x86, so I've created two projects of my Android Project and added ARm to one and x86 to the other. The problem that I have is that I don't know how I must configure each project to generate the apk corresponding to the architecture ARM or x86 to have the two apks to publish in Google Play. I have seen the instructions in developer.android.com but I do not understand them, because it talks about NDK, but I do not have any native code. If somebody could tell me what steps I have to follow to generate the apks, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IF you have arm and x86 of some library, that library is using native C code.  If it was pure java there'd be no reason to have separate versions.

Comment: But i can't add the two crosswalk projects to the Android project. I have to have two versiones of my project one with arm crosswalk and other with x86 crosswalk. My dude Is how I must configure them to generate the two apks that I want publish in Google Play. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If the library came with x86 and arm versions, place them in the proper subfolers of your libs directory (or however gradle does it if you use Android Studio).  If it didn't, then you can't support both and use that library.

Comment: First thank you very much for your suggestions, but I use ADT, and in the documentation of Crosswalk says that is necessary to have two projects, the problem that I have is that I do not know how to configure each project depending on the architecture and the documentation in developer.android.com about múltiple apks with different architectures I do not understand it.